# repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
const { data } = this.state;

if (prevState.data.date !== data.date) {
  const startDate = new Date(data.date.startDate);
  const endDate = new Date(data.date.endDate);
  const countDuration = new Date(endDate - startDate).getDate();
  this.setState({
    data: {
      ...this.state.data,
      duration: countDuration,
    },
  });
}

if (prevState.data.duration !== data.duration) {
  const startDate = new Date(data.date.startDate);
  const endDate = new Date(
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + +data.duration - 1)
  );
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    data: {
      ...this.state.data,
      date: {
        ...this.state.data.date,
        endDate: endDate,
      },
    },
  });
}
```

}

But this gives me error, saying Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: it's very risky to have setState in componentDidUpdate, also I am quite sure that one of the two "if" condition is always true which is causing the state update loop

Comment: Obviously one of those conditions is always returning true, trigger a `setState` every re-render. You'll have to print out the values and start narrowing down what's going wrong, likely how you're updating the nested state values

Comment: i am suspecting that `prevState.data.date !== data.date` always returns true and will always be executed. this might be because you're trying to compare two objects that has a property of type Date

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-rosalind-bld6g?file=/src/parts/BookingForm.js I am really confused

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're changing the data.date and data.duration properties in the wrong place.  As a result, the conditions `prevState.data.date !== data.date` and `prevState.data.duration !== data.duration` are never evaluating to `true` and thus the `setState` calls happen each time, causing an infinite loop